# How to remove gunpowder virus?

Tags: security, 4.2-jelly-bean, malware

I have recently been having problems on my device which includes random apps appearing on my phone and some chinese app that somehow was "pre-installed". As i scoured the internet for answers, i  learnt that my phone had contacted a virus called gunpowder virus that attacks from Nintendo emulators. Can factory reset resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the infected app **wasn't** able to gain root and/or infect the `/system` partition, a factory reset **will** fix it.

However, if it was ... it would require re-flashing the ROM.

Comment: Or gaining root, so OP could manually delete the app on **/system** without having to mess up things too much.

Answer (score 0):

If your device doesn't have the virus and you still want to remove the pre-built chinese apps, You can use a program called MTK Droid Tools..

It was designed for mtk handsets but the Chinese software removal tool only uses adb and root access to remove chinese ime etc...